# Is it possible to configure Spring OAuth1 in Java not XML?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to build an OAuth1 authorization server using Spring. My Spring Security configurations are in Java and the configurations I have for OAuth1 are in XML.

When I start up the server I get an error saying No bean named 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'

This, I think, is because Spring loads XML configs first that contain the OAuth stuff and would then move to the Java configs. But whatever it is looking for cannot be found because it hasn't been loaded yet. Maybe.

I want to find out if it's possible to have the OAuth1 configs in Java an not in XML?